# Extra space in Imageview inside viewgroup inside horisontalscrollView

Tags: android, android-layout

Here is my problem. I have a Horizontal scrollView in which I have a Relative layout with couple of images inside. The problem is that the first image is set to wrap_content width but it makes extra space at the end. Can you please tell me how I can fix this without setting the scale type to some kind of crop. I have posted the screenshots of what I get. The white part is the extra space at the end of the scroll which is part of the imageview. Also below that I have posted the code. Thanks

[image]
[image]

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrollBg"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:contentDescription="@string/content_description"
            android:src="@drawable/bg_login" />

        <ImageView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/treeImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/tree4" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found a solution. I just added `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in the imageview with extra space. That fixed the problem